# estimate for Möbius function of order k

Tags: sums-of-squares, mobius-function

Let $\mu_{k}(n)$ be the MÖBIUS function of order $k$, defined by
$$
\mu_{k}(n)=
\begin{cases} 1 &\text{if }\:  n=1,\\ 
0 &\text{if }\:  p^{k+1}\mid n, \\ 
(-1)^r  & \text{if }\: n = p^k_1· · · p^k_r\prod_{i>r} p_i^{α_i}, \quad0<\alpha_i<k, \\
1 & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

Under this definition, what could be this $$\sum_{n\leq x}\mu_k(n)^2\:?$$
Any small hint is welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This $\mu_k(n)^2$ is simply the indicator function of the $(k+1)$-free numbers—it equals $1$ if $n$ is not divisible by the $(k+1)$st power of a prime and $0$ otherwise. It is well known that
$$
\sum_{n\le x} \mu_k(n)^2 \sim \frac x{\zeta(k+1)},
$$
generalizing the case $k=1$.

Indeed, one can even show using standard multiplicative-function techniques that for $k\ge2$,
$$
\sum_{n\le x} \mu_k(n) \sim x \prod_p \bigg( 1 - \frac2{p^k} + \frac1{p^{k+1}} \bigg),
$$
where the product is over all primes $p$. (The case $k=1$ is harder, essentially equivalent to the prime number theorem.) From these two results one can work out the density of those numbers $n$ for which $\mu_k(n)=1$ or $\mu_k(n)=-1$ or $\mu_k(n)=0$.

Comment: Well-known ?? What is the abscissa of convergence of $(\sum \mu_m m^{-s})(\sum_n \mu_k(n)^2 n^{-s})$ and its value at $1$ ? The OP probably wants to know that the result follows from there.